# For loop with To Variable

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm having a slightly bizarre issue.

I have the following loop (just a snippet as the code is rather large):

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim wsName As String
Dim A As Integer
Dim ExtraArray() As Variant

For I = 1 To WS_Count

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     'Some Code'
     Sheets(wsName).Copy After:=Sheets(wsName)
     Sheets(wsName + " (2)").Name = ExtraArray(A, 2)
     I = I + 1

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Next I
```

There is a lot of other code but I do not believe this to be the problem.

If I add additional sheets whilst in the For loop and add 1 to I and also recalculate WS_Count at the end of the For loop and at the beginning of the loop to make sure it is correct, should this in theory work?

Or does vba not allow for the ad-hoc modification of the For loop variable, in this case 'WS_Count'. Does it just see the original value instead?

My loop works up until a certain point (roughly the original number held in WS_Count and then I resets back to 0.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *Or does vba not allow for the ad-hoc modification of the For loop variable, in this case 'WS_Count'. Does it just see the original value instead?* - This is how it works. You cannot adjust the ending count during the loop. I am sure there are ways around it and even answers for it on this site. (I don't know off top of head though). If adding a new worksheet is not conditional then just do so before loop. Or try a `Do Until Loop` where you can adjust the value of `WS_COUNT` and have the Until check update with each iteration. Like `Do Until i>WS_COUNT` or something.

Comment: @Soctt thanks for the reply, I wondered if that was the case but thought it seemed like a stupid thing to happen considering you can use variables within the for loop.. Let's see if there is a work around or I'll have a look at doing the loop before, I think it will just be a lot more inefficient, but if it works, it works

Comment: If you are not sure about the upper limit, its better to use `Do`/`While` Loop. That's the only elegant solution for you.

Comment: If you were to change the For loop to a While (I <= WS_Count) that should work. You'll have to define I outside the loop and increment I at the end of each iteration

Comment: Use `while`, which also supports the empty loop (i.e. no iterations if begin > end)

Comment: The the other thing to consider is that if adding sheets is **not conditional** then a Do While Loop will be infinite.

Comment: FYI - It's similar to using a `For Each WS in Thisworkbook.Sheets` loop, once the For Each (and for i = x to y) is initialised it can't be altered. If I add a sheet for each sheet in the book then it doesn't start counting those added sheets and go on infinitely.